# How can I enumerate a tensor with unknown dim in tensorflow?

Tags: python, keras

I have a tensor of shape(?,7,7,512), how can I enumerate all the tensor of shape(7,7,512)?

Comment: ? means batch as you know. So what you want is to see all tensors in the batch? Where do you want to do this, in the model?